# com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzq.zzb(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase

**Environment**

- Android device: `MI 5\ MI 6`
- Android OS version: `8.0.0`
- Google Play Services version: without google service
- Firebase/Play Services SDK version: `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0`、`com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.1.0`
- TargetSdkVersion : 26

**Problem**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void     com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzq.zzb(boolean)' on a null object reference
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzg.zzc(Unknown Source:2)
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzk.run(Unknown Source:4)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**LogCat**

```
FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source:72)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzc(Unknown Source:49)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:119)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:28)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1927)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1902)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6425)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5939)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5851)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1689)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
    at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:768)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1940)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1929)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzwp.zza(Unknown Source:32)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzws.zzry(Unknown Source:33)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzws.get(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzex.get(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfg.zziu(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfg.isLoggable(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfg.zza(Unknown Source:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfi.log(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgl.<init>(Unknown Source:226)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgl.zzg(Unknown Source:28)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source:72) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzc(Unknown Source:49) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:119) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:28) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1927) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1902) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6425) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5939) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5851) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1689) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6683) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 



    java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
    at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:768)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1940)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1929)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zza.zza(Unknown Source:38)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzq.<init>(Unknown Source:145)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzg.zzp(Unknown Source:127)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzh.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzq.zzb(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzg.zzc(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzk.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

It seems that the SecurityException causes the `Firebase API initialization failure`, then some NullPointerExceptions comes.

I've try to downgrade the `Performance Tools`, it's no use.
Then i set `TargetSdkVersion` from 26 to 23, the problem dismiss.

Comment: Internet permission given in manifest?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio 3.X, [the recommended version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#add-performance-monitoringto-your-app) of `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins` is 1.1.5. And `firebase-perf:15.2.0`.

Comment: I am getting the same error ```Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority firebase``` This error only occurs when I use ```Run App```, if I properly signed apk and install it the error disappears.

Comment: @ABK the permission already exist

Comment: @Michal_196 I update the firebase sdk, the generate a signed release ask, but the crash occurred again :(

Comment: @daque I think the problem is that you don't have ```PlayServices``` installed.

Comment: Same for Redmi Note 5

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80555710

Comment: Intended behaviour. Sigh. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80555710

Answer (score 0):

Add this to bottom `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in app level  '
and use [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) latest firebase depenedencies,  and if you are using android studio 3.x version use `'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'`

Comment: I've checked my app's `build.gradle`, `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` already exist

Comment: use this update dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0` and i have updated my answer let me know if it is helpfull

Comment: The problem still exist, I update to `com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5`

Comment: can you provide your app-level gradle info?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#prerequisites) indicates that Firebase Performance Monitoring depends on Google Play services:

> Before you begin, you need a few things set up in your environment:
>
> - A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and **Google Play services 15.2.0 or higher**
> - The Google Play services SDK from the Google Repository, available in the Android SDK Manager
> - The latest version of Android Studio, version 2.2 or higher